# Handle - Windows Service

Tags: winapi, windows-services

How do I get the 'Handle' of the Windows Service, so as to pass Memory Mapped messages from a windows application. Both written in Delphi.

Comment: [`OpenService`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684330(v=vs.85).aspx) ?

Comment: @TLama: `OpenService()` does not return a handle that you can send messages to. However, it does return a handle that can be used with `ControlService()`, if the messages do not require any parameters.

Comment: @Remy, I'm aware of its purpose. I've dropped that comment because the  `SC_HANDLE` returned by the `OpenService` call is the only handle I can think of when talking about Windows services. And the question specifically asks how to get a service handle (though it's not the right question to ask).

Answer (score 2):

The handle of the service is not what you need here. Memory mapped files are named kernel objects. So you need to agree on a name for your file mapping and use that to link your two processes.

When you call `CreateFileMapping` to create the file mapping, or open an existing file mapping created by the other process, you pass the name as the last argument. You'll need to use the `Global\` namespace prefix to ensure that the file mapping is in the global namespace and so accessible from different sessions.

Memory mapped files are an unusual choice for IPC between service and desktop. One would more commonly expect to see named pipes or sockets.

Comment: Do note the following in the `CreateFileMapping()` [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366537.aspx): "Creating a file mapping object in the global namespace from a session other than session zero requires the `SeCreateGlobalPrivilege` privilege." As such, you should use `CreateFileMapping()` in the service and `OpenFileMapping()` in the app, as an app is not likely to have the `SeCreateGlobalPrivilege` privilege unless it is running as an admin.

Comment: I have been using TcpIp Sockets for IPC but have to deal with Firewalls unnecessarily blocking my application. Named pipes too will have similar issues. If I use Memory Mapped messages Firewalls will not block my application.  speed of communication can be very high and I need the other application to respond instantly.

Comment: Using File Mapping will be heavier on resourse and also I need that the receiving application's event is trigerred as in wmcopydata()

Comment: There is no such thing as a memory mapped message. There are memory mapped files. Which is what I assume you asked about.

Comment: Sorry I do not know the correct terminology, but below code is what I want to use for IPC
and fail to have a handle of the service. 


function ...
var
  pMsg:string;
  copyDataStruct : TCopyDataStruct;
begin
  pMsg:='Msg from exe1 to exe2';
  copyDataStruct.dwData := Integer(cdtString);    
  copyDataStruct.cbData := 1 + Length(pMsg);
  copyDataStruct.lpData := PChar(pMsg);
  SendMessage(OthExeHndl, WM_COPYDATA,0,Integer(@copyDataStruct));
end;

procedure TForm3.WMCopyData(var Msg: TWMCopyData);
begin
  Memo1.Lines.Add('Recvd '+pchar(msg.CopyDataStruct.lpData));

Comment: You need a window handle in order to use SendMessage. However, you cannot send messages to windows in a different session. So that approach is no good. Use sockets or named pipes.